# Making certain calculations to working hours to return two dates with moment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I have array of days. Each day is an object with open / close times. 0 -1440 minutes. for instance:

```
const array = [
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 510, // 08:30 <- same day
   close: 1260  // 21:00 <- same day
  }
 }
];
```

The result would look like this:

```
// if current time is: "2017-01-10T14:53:45Z" for example
{
 open: "2017-01-10T08:30:00Z",
 close: "2017-01-11T21:00:00Z"
}
```

So the mechanism should loop over array, find the min open, and max close and understand which one is past midnight to add / subtract 1 day to get the example result I mentioned. What I did so far:

```js
const array = [
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 510, // 08:30 <- same day
   close: 1260  // 21:00 <- same day
  }
 }
];

let range = {};
let temp_from = [];
let temp_to = [];

array.forEach((a) => {
 const { hours } = a;
 const open = moment.utc(hours.open * 60000).format('HH:mm'); // ex 21:00
 const close = moment.utc(hours.close * 60000).format('HH:mm'); // ex 21:00
 const todayUTC = moment.utc();
 const hourUTC = todayUTC.format('H');
 const minutesUTC = todayUTC.format('mm');
 const secondsUTC = todayUTC.format('ss');
 const CURRENT_TIME = (hourUTC * 60) + (minutesUTC * 1) + (secondsUTC / 60); // exact time 0 - 1440
 console.log('open', open.split(':')[0]);
   temp_from.push(
     moment.utc().set({
       hour: open.split(':')[0],
       minute: open.split(':')[1],
       second: 0,
     }).format()
   )
   temp_to.push(
      moment.utc().set({
       hour: close.split(':')[0],
       minute: close.split(':')[1],
       second: 0,
     }).add(hours.open > hours.close ? 1 : 0, 'days').format()
   )
})

console.log(temp_from, temp_to);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure about the approach, and if the mechanism can be broken?

Comment: This question is kind of confusing. You have three days, but you want a single result with an open date/time and a close date/time, but those dates should only be one day apart? Why wouldn't the first and last dates be three days apart?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fine approach. The only thing I see is that if there is a 24h opening time you should use:

```
.add(hours.open >= hours.close ? 1 : 0, 'days').format()
```

instead of:

```
.add(hours.open > hours.close ? 1 : 0, 'days').format()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what end point you're aiming for, but the code you have can be simplified by not converting things from numbers to strings and back again.

I removed the CURRENT_TIME constant, as it wasn't used anywhere. If you want it back, just use the `hours()`, etc. methods to get the values you want, rather than formatting and multiplying strings.

I'm also taking Borre's answer into account below.

```js
const array = [
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 1260, // 21:00 <- same day
   close: 510  // 08:30 <- next day
  }
 },
 {
  hours: {
   open: 510, // 08:30 <- same day
   close: 1260  // 21:00 <- same day
  }
 }
];

let range = {};
let temp_from = [];
let temp_to = [];

array.forEach((a) => {
 const { hours } = a;
 const open = moment.utc(hours.open * 60000);
 const close = moment.utc(hours.close * 60000);
// startOf('day') will get midnight, UTC for today
 const todayUTC = moment.utc().startOf('day');
// Rather than splitting the time formatted as a string, just use the methods
// provided by Moment.js to get the values you want
   temp_from.push(
     todayUTC.clone().set({
       hour: open.hours(),
       minute: open.minutes(),
       second: 0,
     }).format()
   )
   temp_to.push(
      todayUTC.clone().set({
       hour: close.hours(),
       minute: close.minutes(),
       second: 0,
     }).add(hours.open >= hours.close ? 1 : 0, 'days').format()
   )
})

console.log(temp_from, temp_to);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```